# On blur in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have four inputs in my web page. The requirement is when the user fills the 1 input then its value should fill in 3 input and 3 input color should change into red same for second input. But when we fill 1 input then 4 input color changes to red.

Here's an example http://jsfiddle.net/SXzyR/

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>    
<script type="text/javascript">

$(function(){       
    $('input').blur(function(){         
        txtval()            
        })      
    })
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">    
function txtval(){      
    document.getElementById('myid3').value = document.getElementById('myid1').value;
    document.getElementById('myid4').value = document.getElementById('myid2').value;

    document.getElementById('myid3').style.color="#ff0000"
    document.getElementById('myid4').style.color="#ff0000"
}
</script>
</head>    
<body>
1
<input type="text" id="myid1" value="Enter name"/>
2
<input type="text" id="myid2" value="Enter name"/>
3
<input type="text" id="myid3" value="Enter name"/>
4
<input type="text" id="myid4" value="Enter name"/>
</body>
```

Comment: why are you mixing both js and jquery code. It does'nt look good

Comment: @InternalServerError Code is not a visual element in a website.

Comment: @Joonas i know that,we should encourage to follow coding guidelines

Comment: @InternalServerError coding guidelines? "Thou shalt not write vanilla javascript when using jquery, because it doesn't look good"?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

check this jsFiddle...

http://jsfiddle.net/SXzyR/8/

the problem was becuase your blur function was for all input element.....

modified a bit of your code so you don't have to change or add any attributes.. jus need to check conditions

Comment: I choosing this answer as best answer because he did change my script a lot

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple solution. Check the `id` of the element which the `blur` event fired on, and update the corresponding elements `value` and colour:

```
$('input').blur(function(){
    if (this.id == 'myid1') {
      $('#myid3').css('color', '#FF0000').val(this.value);  
    } else if (this.id == 'myid2') {
      $('#myid4').css('color', '#FF0000').val(this.value);
    }            
})
```

[Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SXzyR/6/)

Answer (score 0):

Because the txtval() method is called on all input blur events and your method does'nt handled any case to prevent highlighting the 2nd input. So all 4 lines in your method are executed and hence 4th input is also coloured!

here's the updated code:
http://jsfiddle.net/SXzyR/

```
$(function(){

$('#myid1').blur(function(){
    $('myid3').value=$(this).value();
    $('#myid3').css('color','#FF0000') 

    });
$('#myid2').blur(function(){
    $('myid3').value=$(this).value();
    $('#myid4').css('color','#FF0000') 
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your html code like this:

```
1
<input type="text" id="myid1" value="Enter name" rel="myid3" />
2
<input type="text" id="myid2" value="Enter name" rel="myid4" />
3
<input type="text" id="myid3" value="Enter name"/>
4
<input type="text" id="myid4" value="Enter name"/>
```

here is the js code

```
$(function(){

    $('input[rel]').each(function(){
       $(this).blur(function(){
           $("#" + $(this).attr("rel")).val($(this).val()).css('color','#FF0000') ;  
       });        
    });

})
```

and here is the example http://jsfiddle.net/SXzyR/2/

Answer (score 0):

Thats because you've added event handler for `input` with `$('input')` Which means `textval()` should be called on the `blur` event of any/all the `inputs`.. What you can do is

1) Pass parameter to `textval()` specifying which to turn red.
2) You can attach event handler to particular `input` to specify the other `input` that needs to be turned red...